# Can fluorescent recessed lighting with four wires be converted to a two wire incandescent socket?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have ceiling lights in the kitchen that are fluorescent recessed can lighting with four wires, can they be converted to a two wire incandescent socket?

Comment: The can is probably not rated for the heat an incandescent bulb would release.

Comment: I want to put a led retro fit into the space with a incandescent socket type.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Technically, I believe that's a "medium Edison-base socket"... I'm not sure whether you can do that retrofit without dismounting the fixture and rewiring the fixture to eliminate the ballast and starter.

Comment: Use a candelabra type socket, LEDs are readily available with that socket, but incandescents over about 25W are quite scarce.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'd have to completely rewire the fixture -- the four-pin base is a sign that the fixture has an integral fluorescent ballast and starter, which provide the current limited, high-ish voltage needed for a fluorescent tube (irrespective of what shape it's twisted into) to operate.